# Is Capitalism (or any other games of that sort) not a valid card game here?

Tags: discussion

why are there no questions on caps? I have searched the site and have found nothing on games of that sort.

Comment: sorry if this question is nonrelevant...

Comment: i sorta cant...

Comment: Are you sure? Unless you're somehow question banned there, questions can be equally asked here or on this site's meta. (That is also not the global meta stack overflow)

Comment: ...my rep is too low

Comment: Oh, right. Meta requires 5 rep, I forgot about that. I've put a vote in to migrate it there in any case.

Comment: ok thanks. whitespace doesn't count? darn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Please go ahead and ask your question.**

Traditional card games are within scope for the site.

There aren't any questions about Capitalism because nobody has asked one yet (at least, under that name — I haven't searched all the variants).

Don't worry about that when asking your new question: the only real consequence is that a higher-rep user will have to come in later to add the tag.

Answer (score 2):

I  don't hang around on the meta for this stackexchange, so apologies if I missed anything specific to here.

Are you sure there are no questions? Many standard deck card games go by many names, for instance what you call capitalism is known by (from [this site](http://www.pagat.com/climbing/asshole.html))

Scum, Asshole, Arsehole, Rich Man Poor Man, Bum, Landlord, Emperors and Scum, Root Beer, Butthead, Capitalism, Warlords and Scumbags, Trouduc, Trou du Cul, Einer ist immer der Arsch, Hűbéres, Sluitspieren and Klootzakken.

I kind of cheated by including the foreign names to get to 17 names, but there are 11 English names for that game, so finding a question about it can be complicated, as everyone will use their own name.

To make things more complicated, it is hard to answer questions about these games since there are nearly as many rule variations are there are names.

I believe that a question related to these games would be valid, but I would not know a good way to standardize given that there are many games like that.

Comment: that is a good point :)